# Read/Write ArrayList String to file

Tags: android

Hi I have same problem by Writing String ArrayList to file and Reading.

This is my code for writing

```
File SettingsPath = getFilesDir();
    String strSettingsPath = SettingsPath.toString() + "/settings.txt";
    File file = new File (strSettingsPath);
    if (!file.exists()) {

        File removeFile = new File(strSettingsPath.toString());
        boolean deleted = removeFile.delete();

    }

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos =
                new FileOutputStream(
                        new File(strSettingsPath));

        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(this.strSettings);
        os.close();
        Log.v("","File has been written");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();


    }
```

And this is for Reading

```
public void reader(View v) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File SettingsPath = getFilesDir();
    String strSettingsPath = SettingsPath.toString() + "/settings.txt";
    List<String> Settings = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader readerL = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strSettingsPath));
    String line;
   try{
       //line = readerL.readLine();
       while ((line = readerL.readLine()) != null) {
           Settings.add(line);
           System.out.println("The Setting line is " + Settings);
       }
       readerL.close();
   }catch (IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

By reading I get This

The Setting line is [����sr��java.util.ArrayListx����a���I��sizexp������w������t��]
 The Setting line is [����sr��java.util.ArrayListx����a���I��sizexp������w������t��, test@test.comt��passwordt��  itdguccgjx]

and I need like this

test@test.com
password
itdguccgjx

What is wrong?

Sorry for my bad English.

Hi

I will like this.

Textbox1
Textbox2
Textbox3

.......

If I will get value of arraylist.get(1).tostring I get Textbox2

Comment: like this

test@test.com password itdguccgjx

Comment: If you use an ObjectOutputStream for writing then i would think you would use an ObjectInputStream for reading.

Comment: You are starting to delete a file if a file does not exist.

Comment: if (file.exists()) if(!file.delete()) return; But you do not have to delete the file as the new FileOutputastream will do that.

Comment: @greenapps but ObjectInputStream.readLine not working and readUTF

Comment: Are you using writeLine()? No. So why readLine()? Use readObject() if you used writeObject().

Comment: Change to readObject and it working. Thanks. And how to split it? To array like email =array[0].toString?

Comment: To split what ?

Comment: Arraylist. Then I will use it as a value. It will be read 4 values.

Comment: Use the list.get(index) function to retrieve a specific value.

Comment: If I use Arraylist.get(0).tostrind I get this text1, text2, text3, ... and I need text1 next line text2 next line text 3 how can I make it need I to split arraylist?

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Put what you want in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: Post updated I by using list.get(index) if index =0 I get a line like this text1, text2, text3..... and if I change index to 1 I get error that arraylist count =1

Comment: Are you not able to first show us whats in your arraylist? Show how you defined it. And then code or ask what you want?